# HTTP2はTCP受信ウィンドウと輻輳ウィンドウ問題を直接は解決しない？

Tags: http, ssl, http2

HTTP2は多重ストリームで高速化・効率化を実現しますが、TCP受信ウィンドウと輻輳ウィンドウ問題を直接は解決しない？と理解しています。
正しいでしょうか？

HTTP2を採用してもTCPパケットおよびTLSパケットのフォーマット自体は今まで通りであり、設定された受信ウィンドウサイズや輻輳ウィンドウのサイズおよびスロースタートやリセットの仕組みは変わらないと思っています。なのでTCPレイヤーに伏在していた問題は残り続けるのではないかと思ってます。

べつにHTTP2に意味がないとかそういう話ではなく、TCPパケットが抱えていた問題は残るので、そこの設定のチューニングはHTTP2が採用された後も意味があるかどうかを知りたい、ということです。たとえばアクセス負荷があらかじめ計算できていてマシンスペックに余裕があるのなら、ウィンドウスケールを使うなど。

理解が間違っていたらご指摘ください。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TCPの問題はそのまま残り、意味のあるTCP層チューニングの余地も残ります。コネクションの数・データ転送量等は変化しますが、単に解決すべきパラメーターが変わってくるだけで。
トランスポート層近辺の問題、TCP・TLS層に残された課題を解決しようとしているのはHTTP/2ではなく、QUICやWebRTCのデータチャネルなどがありますね。(後者はHTTP/2を上に載せるわけではないですが)